# How to find popular Google search terms for a particular demographic/location/interest group?

Tags: search, google-analytics, ads, google-trends

I'm starting an online business targeted at a particular demographic and interests so I would like to produce content targeted at what this particular target market are actually searching for.

Google Ads allowed me to refine my target audience to the exact categories (demographics and interests) I needed but I couldn't tell me what that category of people tend to search for except for the tiny subset that happens to click on one of my ads which is very rare given I am just starting with a small budget. I would like to know the most popular search terms for everyone in the categories I specified not just those who happened to click on my ads.

I tried Google Trends, that told me the popularity of a particular search term for a given country but that's too broad - I need to narrow it down to a particular city, age group, parental status and interests. Google Trends also helped me find popular related search terms given a particular search term so I could try using that to see if there are any common popular related search terms related to my guesses but I could miss terms related to terms I never thought of.

I could try producing content across a rage of topics which I think my target audience might be interested in and then analyse the results using Google Ads but that could be a very expensive trial and error process and I might miss more popular topics which I never thought of.

Of course I could try to ask my target market in person directly (by interrupting people in the street!) but that would be very expensive for me because I would have to travel to and stay at the location where my online business is targeted, hoping to meet people with the exact same demographic and interests that I am looking.

I'm sure there must be a way to figure this out using the the Google search analytics. Essentially, all I need is a list of most popular recent Google search terms for a particular location, demographic and interests group in Google Analytics. Could anyone help me understand how to get this list?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few considerations, even if you found an answer.

Take a look at the AdRoll platform. Here's a potentially helpful article from them about [target audience and demographics](https://www.adroll.com/blog/5-tools-to-learn-about-your-target-audience).

A recent article about [AdWords demographic targeting](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2016/09/12/demographic-targeting-for-search-campaigns). An older looking article, [connecting demographics to search queries](https://searchengineland.com/connecting-demographics-search-queries-243440), but page's source code suggests an update this year.

Last but not least, you're probably [eligible](https://support.google.com/business/answer/10011813) to talk with a [Google Small Business Advisor](https://business.google.com/advisors/expertise).